# How do I checkout part of a tree in subclipse?

Tags: subclipse

I am using SVN plugin for eclipse (subclipse), and want to do a Checkout (or import) of an existing repository into eClipse workspace. However, I only want to checkout certain portision of the file tree. Is there a way I can do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You may be somewhat limited (and it may not even be possible) by using Subclipse itself.  You're best bet is to use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html) or command line client and do a [sparse checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) on the **top level directory** that *contains* the child structure(s) you want to check out

```
svn checkout svn://repository/path --depth empty
```

Once you have a sparse checkout of the top most folder, you can do svn update to retrieve any child folders you want, controlling their depth as you see fit.

```
cd the-parent-folder
svn update --set-depth files some-child-directory
```

The more complicated you get with wanting to avoid certain paths in subversion, the more manual updates you will have to do on every folder you actually want from the repository.
Once you get done checking out the files, you can import the directory into Eclipse and it should function normally from that point on.